# E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bashsenpai/cli/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I've tried the different solutions listed in here:

[What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

First solution: ppa-purge

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bashsenpai/cli/ubuntu
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bashsenpai/cli/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

Second solution: add-apt-repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:bashsenpai/cli/ubuntu
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~bashsenpai/cli/ubuntu'.
The user named '~bashsenpai' has no PPA named 'cli/ubuntu'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'cli':  BashSenpai CLI
(gives me the prompt back, won't let me 'choose' anything)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:bashsenpai/cli
```